# Batch file doesn't execute everything that it should do

Tags: android, cordova, batch-file, ionic-framework, cmd

I have a batch file that should do things automatically and if I type the instructions one after each other by myself everything works fine...
But in the batch file it stops executing after the "ionic cordova build android" command.
Code:

```
cd Desktop
cd Schooltastic
start "" "C:/Users/lukas/Desktop/Schooltastic/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/"
ionic cordova build android
cordova build android
```

Maybe it is important to say, that this command takes a few seconds, maybe that's a problem...
But do you know any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
call ionic ...
```

should cure the problem. Starts the procedure `ionic` then waits for completion before proceeding